# Excel VBA Moving Range of Data to New Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I did something wrong here. The range being moved is only grabbing the first value in the array, the resize statement is not moving the entire array as expected. Can someone point out my error?

This statement is not working except to bring over K2 from the stated range and lrow is being calculated as expected:
"With shtTarget.Range("K2:K" & lrow)
    BET_ws.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With"

Additionally, I have had a great deal of trouble selecting a tab after opening the document. I need to find a way to select the 1st tab named "*H*" but Set "shtTarget = wbkTarget.Worksheets(""*"H"*"")" doesn't work.

Full Block:

```
Sub BetConverter()

Dim wbkTarget As Workbook
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
Dim BET_ws As Worksheet
Dim shtTarget As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long 'last row variable
Dim lcol As Long 'last column variable
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim MyDat As Variant

'kill clunky processes
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'delete summary tab if it exists
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BET Consolidated").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'On Error GoTo Errhandler

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Macro")).Name = "BET Consolidated" 'create new tab

Set BET_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BET Consolidated")

MsgBox ("Please Select the Bid Entry Tool to be Consolidated in the following File Dialog Box.")

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Bid Entry Tool to be Consolidated")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Set wbkTarget = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)

Set shtTarget = wbkTarget.Worksheets("SC-H8888-008-000")

lrow = shtTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row

With shtTarget.Range("K2:K" & lrow)
    BET_ws.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

With shtTarget.Range("O2:O" & lrow)
BET_ws.Range("B1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

With shtTarget.Range("P2:P" & lrow)
BET_ws.Range("C1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

For Each ws In wbkTarget.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "User Guide" And ws.Name <> "PBP2020_Dictionary" Then
        Set shtTarget = wbkTarget.ActiveSheet
        lastrow = shtTarget.Cells(shtTarget.Rows.Count, 38).End(xlUp).Row
        lcol = BET_ws.Cells(1, BET_ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        With shtTarget.Range("AB1:AB" & lastrow)
            BET_ws.Cells(1, lcol + 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
        End With
    End If
Next ws


'Format Header for Summary Table
With BET_ws.Range("A1:C1")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .Font.Size = 11
    .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    .RowHeight = 60
    .ColumnWidth = 32
End With

'bring back clunky processes
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

MsgBox ("Macro Complete!")

Exit Sub

Errhandler:

'bring back clunky processes
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Select Case err.Number
    'different error handling here
    Case Else
    MsgBox "Error " & err.Number & ": " & err.Description, vbCritical, "Summary"
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Your range should be `"K2:K" & lr`

Comment: Good call, I am still very rusty. That fixes those middle range statements but not the one in the For Each statement towards the end. Im guess I need to change something since Im working .Cells instead of .Range there? Not sure what

Comment: For that you need to do Range(Cells(starting cell), Cells(ending cell))